# Was the wrong type of caulk used to seal the quartz between the counter and wall

Tags: countertops, caulk, quartz

I have quartz countertops, the contractor used a clear caulk. The caulk has turned yellow and is flaking away, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

One reason might have been old caulk.

The way to fix is to remove all old caulk and redo.

Caulk has maybe 6 months to a year of shelf life(unopen), so check the date.

The type of caulk is probably not important unless you wanted to paint it after.  Silicon types do not like paint, but are usually used for counter tops.

Make sure to let it cure before cleaning.